# Button that use select

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to make a button that have the action of "SELECT" not to load the scene directly . I made a game with 3 rooms , and I want the player to select the room and then press another button to play (like START) . How I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

[System.Serializable]
public struct SceneButton
{
    public Button Button;
    public string SceneName;

    public void TurnOn()
    {
        // Do what you want to indicate the button is selected
        // Animate it, change colour, ....
    }

    public void TurnOff()
    {
        // Do what you want to indicate the button is NOT selected
        // Animate it, change colour, ....
    }
}
// Attach this script to the gameObject you want
// On an empty or the confirm button for instance
public class SceneSelector : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Fill the array in the inspector
    [SerializeField]
    private SceneButton[] sceneButtons;

    private int selectedButtonIndex = -1;

    private void Start()
    {
        SetupButtons();
    }

    private void SetupButtons()
    {
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < sceneButtons.Length ; ++i )
        {
            int index = i;
            sceneButtons[i].Button.onClick.AddListener( () => SelectButton( index ) );
        }
    }

    public void SelectButton( int buttonIndex )
    {
        if ( selectedButtonIndex >= 0 )
            sceneButtons[selectedButtonIndex].TurnOff();

        selectedButtonIndex = buttonIndex;

        if ( selectedButtonIndex >= 0 )
            sceneButtons[selectedButtonIndex].TurnOn();
    }

    // Use this function as a callback of your button's `onClick`
    // used to confirm the choice of the user
    public void LoadSelectedScene()
    {
        if ( selectedButtonIndex >= 0 )
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene( sceneButtons[selectedButtonIndex].SceneName );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: sceneButtons[i].Button.onClick.AddListener(() => Select button(index)); here is an error at Select Button

Comment: My bad, I am on my mobilephone. Fixed the code of my answer.

Comment: This script I should attached to a button? or to the Panel? Canvas?

Comment: As I said in the comments, you can attach it to the gameObject you want. Even an empty gameObject would do the job. But attaching it to the panel containing all your buttons or the "confirm" button can be logical.

Comment: Did you fill the inspector as I indicated in the comments of the code and provided the `LoadSelectedScene` in the `onClick` event of your confirm button, **as indicated in the comments of the code**?

Comment: I had the time to fix and test the code on my computer. Everything works here.

Comment: no , when I put the script at ONCLICK it doesn't appear anything https://paste.pics/da670557584f06391a0064ea6aa1842d

Comment: You have to drag & drop the gameObject holding the script, not the script itself....

Comment: Nope still enters in the game automatically

Comment: Then, you have other scripts interfering with this one. In your previous screenshot, I see that the `MainMenuControl.changemenuscene` is called in the `onClick` button you have shown. **Only the confirm button must have the `LoadSelectedScene` function), the other buttons used to "select the scene to load" must be provided in the `sceneButtons` array of the provided script.